# Bluetooth connection using socket rfcomm

Tags: c++, c, linux, bluetooth

I have two Bluetooth devices and I'm trying to make two rfcomm connections, one connection per device.

I'm using bluez rfcomm socket

```
addr.rc_family = AF_BLUETOOTH;
addr.rc_channel = (uint8_t) 1;
str2ba( dest, &addr.rc_bdaddr );

// connect to server
s = socket(AF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTPROTO_RFCOMM);

// set disconnect timeout to 2sec
struct timeval tv;
tv.tv_sec = 2;
setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO,(struct timeval *)&tv,sizeof(struct timeval));

// make connection
status = connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));
```

How I select a device to make the connection?

Comment: What is the Question ? Can you please re-phrase your question

Comment: The main question is, with two bluetooth dongles plugged in computer, choose  the dongle that  will be used to make a rfcomm connection using bluez rfcomm sockets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot do this, the bluez bluetooth stack will work on only one dongle i.e local bluetooth device at any time.

To be able to have a singe instance of the bluetooth stack control 2 bluetooth local dongles will be a big change to the bluez stack.

Comment: This is wrong. Bluez most certainly supports multiple dongles.

Answer (score 1):

I believe bluez supports up to 16 dongles.

You might be interested in the code in this project:
http://diy-machine.blogspot.com/

Comment: edit:Bluez support 16 dongles http://www.kernel.org/doc/ols/2005/ols2005v1-pages-247-252.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You have to call bind() before connect().

Have a look at this:

https://github.com/matlo/l2cap_proxy/blob/master/l2cap_con.c#L197

It's l2cap, but I guess it's also possible for rfcomm.

Comment: Why would bind be required? Its possible to call socket() followed by connect().

Comment: Bind before connect is the posix idiom for setting the source address. The source address is used to determine the outgoing interface. Thus by using bind, you can select a different bt adapter from which to initiate the connection. This is very useful if you need more than 7 connected slave devices prior to BLE.